# Automorphism that the Fukaya category is "blind" to

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, derived-categories, mirror-symmetry, string-theory, geometric-representation-theory

Given a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, there is a natural map
$$ Symp(M,\omega) \to Auteq(D^\pi Fuk(M,\omega))$$
which sends a symplectic automorphism to the $A_\infty$-functor it induces on the Fukaya category (I'm being delibrately vague about which flavor of Fukaya category are we talking about here).

1. Is there any known case of a nontrivial symplectomorphism whose image is the identity functor?
2. Does it matter if we replace $D^\pi Fuk(M,\omega)$ with $Fuk(M,\omega)$?
3. What about if we replace the left-hand side with $\pi_0 Symp(M,\omega)$ (symplectomorphism up to Hamiltonian isotopy) and the right-hand side with $A_\infty$-functors up to $A_\infty$-homotopy?
4. Is there any (physics?) reason to believe that the representation above should actually be faithful for certain manifolds?

Comment: Since $D^\pi\mathcal F$ is defined functorially in $\mathcal F$, it clearly won't see anything more than $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Yes, I agree - but it might see less...

Comment: I'll change the order of 1. and 2. to make it clearer.

Comment: What happens when you take HH?

Comment: @AHusain: If you mean Hochschild cohomology, it is commonly believed that you get the action of $\pi_0 Symp$ on the quantum cohomology $QH^\bullet(M,\omega)$ (endowed with the structure of quantum Massey products and considered as an $A_\infty$-algebra).

Comment: @Nati ,that seems reasonable, but was asking for the corresponding examples where you got some trivial actions on QH so could use those as starting points.